# Getting "xdvipdfmx:fatal: File ended prematurely" error while using pspicture

Tags: xetex, pstricks, texlive-2016, pspicture, texlive-2019

I'm using TeXLive2016 on macOS 10.12 with TeXstudio 2.12.6.
While compiling files containing pspicture with XeLaTeX I get this message:

```
xdvipdfmx:fatal: File ended prematurely Output file removed.
```

Here is a sample:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(0,-1.54)(5.98,1.54)
    \psdots[dotsize=0.09](1.66,1.12)
    \psdots[dotsize=0.09](0.26,-1.28)
    \psdots[dotsize=0.09](4.46,-1.28)
    \psdots[dotsize=0.09](5.86,1.12)
    \psline[linewidth=0.04cm](0.26,-1.28)(1.66,1.12)
    \psline[linewidth=0.04cm](1.66,1.12)(4.46,-1.28)
    \psline[linewidth=0.04cm](4.46,-1.28)(0.26,-1.28)
    \psline[linewidth=0.04cm](5.86,1.12)(4.46,-1.28)
    \usefont{T1}{ppl}{m}{n}
    \rput(1.55,1.31){$2$}
    \usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
    \rput(4.62,-1.375){$3$}
    \usefont{T1}{ppl}{m}{n}
    \rput(5.83,1.33){$4$}
    \usefont{T1}{ppl}{m}{n}
    \rput(0.04,-1.35){$1$}
    \end{pspicture} 
\end{document}
```

I searched a lot but I couldn't find a solution for this situation. I would appreciate any suggestion.

Edit:

for this code:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0,-1.54)(5.98,1.54)
\psdots[dotsize=0.09](1.66,1.12)(0.26,-1.28)(4.46,-1.28)(5.86,1.12)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](0.26,-1.28)(1.66,1.12)(4.46,-1.28)(0.26,-1.28)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](5.86,1.12)(4.46,-1.28)
\rput(1.55,1.31){2}
\rput(4.62,-1.375){3}
\rput(5.83,1.33){4}
\rput(0.04,-1.35){1}
\end{pspicture} 
\end{document}
```

file list is:

```
*File List*
article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
pstricks.sty    2015/11/14 v0.62 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
xetex.def    2016/04/06 v4.08 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (TeX Live/RRM/JK)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
pstricks.tex    2016/05/18 v2.66 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
pst-fp.tex    2016/05/18 v2.66 `PST-fp' (hv)
fontspec.sty    2016/02/01 v2.5a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
expl3.sty    2016/05/18 v6512 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2016/05/18 v6512 L3 programming layer 
l3xdvipdfmx.def    
xparse.sty    2016/05/18 v6512 L3 Experimental document command parser
fontspec-xetex.sty    2016/02/01 v2.5a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
fontenc.sty
eu1enc.def    2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
eu1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
xunicode.sty    2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many other characters in Unicode lower plane
eu1lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2016/05/09 v1.0r Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.10 sample graphics configuration
fontspec.cfg
t3cmr.fd    2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
***********
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 20423 strings out of 493591
 399990 string characters out of 6143545
 386959 words of memory out of 5000000
 23726 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3680 words of font info for 19 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1347 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 46i,5n,42p,10348b,226s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Error 256 (driver return code) generating output;
file document.pdf may not be valid.
```

**Update** I still have the same problem with TeXLive2019 and up-to-date packages.

Comment: You need to either compile via `dvips` and `ps2pdf` or to pass the `shell-escape` option to `xelatex`

Comment: the code works without problems on windows in a current texlive. If you still have the problem it seems to be OS specific and you should report it on the macos or the texlive mailing list.

Comment: I spent quite some time on this bug too, and it turns out that I simply missed `ghostscript` on my system. The error is quite unhelpful to find out the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see it with up-to-date TL 2017 and xelatex. However, you can 
simplify your code:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0,-1.54)(5.98,1.54)
\psdots[dotsize=0.09](1.66,1.12)(0.26,-1.28)(4.46,-1.28)(5.86,1.12)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](0.26,-1.28)(1.66,1.12)(4.46,-1.28)(0.26,-1.28)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](5.86,1.12)(4.46,-1.28)
\rput(1.55,1.31){2}
\rput(4.62,-1.375){3}
\rput(5.83,1.33){4}
\rput(0.04,-1.35){1}
\end{pspicture} 
\end{document}
```

Filelist is at the end of the log file:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
pstricks.sty    2017/09/17 v0.65 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
   iftex.sty    2013/04/04 v0.2 Provides if(tex) conditional for PDFTeX, XeTeX,
 and LuaTeX
shellesc.sty    2016/06/07 v0.02a unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
   xetex.def    2017/06/24 v5.0h Graphics/color driver for xetex
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
pstricks.tex    2017/10/04 v2.77 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
  pst-fp.tex    2017/10/04 v2.77 `PST-fp' (hv)
pstricks.pro    2017/09/18 v. 1.27, PostScript prologue file (hv)
pst-algparser.pro    2011/10/31 v. 0.04, PostScript prologue file (hv)
pst-tools.pro    2012/01/01 v. 0.02, PostScript prologue file (hv)
pst-dots.pro    2006/12/19 v. 2.00, PostScript prologue file (hv)
 ***********
```